# Hide html form after submission?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an HTML form that posts to a php script that then emails me the forms contents.
I'm also using javascript form validation and some jquery ajax so that the page doesn't reload.

HTML -

```
<form action="mail.php" class="contactus" onsubmit="return ValidateRequiredFields();"   name="contactus" method="POST">
<p class="floatleft" style="width:200px; background-color:#FF0000; line-height:50px; margin:0; padding:0;">Nameeeeee</p> <input class="sizetext" type="text" maxlength="10" name="name">
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<p class="floatleft" style="width:200px;">Email</p> <input class="sizetext" type="text" maxlength="10" name="email">
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<p class="floatleft" style="width:200px;">Telephone</p> <input class="sizetext" type="text" maxlength="10" name="telephone">


<p>Priority</p>
<select name="priority" size="1">
<option value="Low">Low</option>
<option value="Normal">Normal</option>
<option value="High">High</option>
<option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>
</select>

</select>
<p>Message</p><textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br />

<br />
<input class="buttonstyle" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>

    <div id="formResponse">
        </div>
```

PHP -

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$priority = $_POST['priority'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Email: $email \n Telephone Number: $telephone \n Priority: $priority \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "myemailaddress";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

Form validation and ajax -

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">


var FormName = "contactus";



var RequiredFields = "name,email,priority,message";



function ValidateRequiredFields()
{
var FieldList = RequiredFields.split(",")
var BadList = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < FieldList.length; i++) {
    var s = eval('document.' + FormName + '.' + FieldList[i] + '.value');
    s = StripSpacesFromEnds(s);
    if(s.length < 1) { BadList.push(FieldList[i]); }
    }
if(BadList.length < 1) { return true; }
var ess = new String();
if(BadList.length > 1) { ess = 's'; }
var message = new String('\n\nThe following field' + ess + ' are required:\n');
for(var i = 0; i < BadList.length; i++) { message += '\n' + BadList[i]; }
alert(message);
return false;
}

function StripSpacesFromEnds(s)
{
while((s.indexOf(' ',0) == 0) && (s.length> 1)) {
    s = s.substring(1,s.length);
    }
while((s.lastIndexOf(' ') == (s.length - 1)) && (s.length> 1)) {
    s = s.substring(0,(s.length - 1));
    }
if((s.indexOf(' ',0) == 0) && (s.length == 1)) { s = ''; }
return s;
}
// -->
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {

                $(".contactus").submit(function() {

                    $.post("mail.php", $(".contactus").serialize(),

                        function(data) {
                            $("#formResponse").html(data);
                        }
                    );
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
```

What I'd like to know is how to hide the form after it's submitted.

Comment: I agree.  0% accept is unacceptable.

Comment: Oh my apologies, I was quite unaware it was proper etiquette to do so. Now done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".contactus").on('submit', function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $.post("mail.php", $(".contactus").serialize(), function(data) {
         $("#formResponse").html(data);
         $this.hide()
    });
    return false;
});
```

Or you could try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".contactus").on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: "mail.php",
           data: $(".contactus").serialize()
        }).done(function() { //done will only hide if the submit is successful, using always instead will alway hide the form
           $this.hide();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: this should work, but only if the post to mail.php is successful, if that file doesn't exist / path is wrong, the form won't hide and neither will the mail be sent. using `.on('submit',...` is the same as `.submit`

Comment: Form works, mail is sent, but it doesn't hide. Am I doing something wrong? Should I be adding something to the form?

Comment: @andy - updated my answer with an ajax function that uses `always()`. Unless there are any other errors in your code, that should always the hide form, regardless of success or error.

Comment: Uh it still doesn't work, I'm probably doing something totally moronic. I add in <script type="text/javascript">
$(".contactus").on('submit', function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: "mail.php",
       data: $(".contactus").serialize()
    }).always(function() {
       $this.hide();
    });
});
</script> and it seems to change nothing, form never hides.

Comment: @andy - Are you preventing the form from actually submitting, see updated answer with preventDefault().

Comment: I don't think I am, it submits alright, I can't get either version of your codes to work.

Comment: www.andrewsmorris.co.uk here's the form in action with the first version of your code.

Comment: Your using jQuery 1.3.2 <- Your getting that from the Google API, try changing the version number to 1.7.2, did it for me ?

Comment: Nope, form still doesn't hide, tried it in multiple browsers and changed jQuery version.

Comment: Use only one funcion at the time, don't try them all at once :) Also, all jQuery code code should be inside a ready function, see updated answer and this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/cZtZ3/)

Comment: Oh cool, that works now - how do I make the one that only hides on successful submission work?

Comment: That means the ajax function always completes, there are three options, `done()`, `always()` and `fail()`, they correspond with the older handlers `success()`, `complete()` and `error()`. I guess you hvae to try them out to see if any of them do what you'd like them to do ? Normally `done()` only fires if the Ajax function does not throw an error, then `fail()` will be fired instead.

Comment: Well thanks for all your help, adeneo, but I don't think I'm going to get this working anytime soon!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('form.contactus').submit(function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```